# What is a good reference that connects calculus with differential geometry?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question

It seems that most texts on differential geometry books tend to take a quantum leap from calculus without refering the latter. Differentials suddenly becomes forms, functions suddenly becomes diffeomorphisms, direction directives suddenly becomes vector fields...

Can someone reference a good text or set of notes that connects the ideas from calculus to differential geometry so that the two subjects are merged together?

Comment: You might take a look at the book From Calculus to Cohomology. They avoid the use of differentiable manifold for half of the book and introduce differential forms in open set in $\mathbb R^m$. That might make your life a bit easier (but there are some algebra in the book... not so sure now)

Comment: It's interesting that the most complete "answer" to this question is the only one posted as a comment - the Dunning-Kruger effect in action.

Comment: @theage Since I'm included in your comment, I can say for sure you are drawing the wrong conclusion.  The reason mine is posted as an answer is, I don't like to post answers in comments.

Comment: you might find http://www.supermath.info/AdvancedCalculus13.pdf useful. I try to start by treating multivariate analysis, Jacobians and all that then I spend the latter half on forms and such. Tu and Lee's manifold texts are certainly helpful, perhaps Conlon, or Munkres also should be considered.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Hey thank you for the wonderful reference! Although I didn't know that liberty university had a math department given all the controversies over creationism

Comment: I'm actually working on differential geometry this summer. I'll post a link if you want. I suppose creationists can also do math. At least, I know a few...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loring W. Tu's book](http://www.amazon.ca/Introduction-Manifolds-Loring-W-Tu/dp/1441973990/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1432974243&sr=8-2&keywords=loring+w.+tu) is probably the most gentle differential geometry text I've seen.

Answer (score 4):

Calculus on Manifolds - Spivak